# Socket Disconnect Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket

Olá tenho um socket no qual quando executo o comando `socket.disconnect()` ele me retornar disconnect is not a function, o que poderia ser ? já tentei varias formas de desconectar e nenhuma resolveu meu problema

```js
var net = require('net');
var clientIn = new net.Socket();
var clientOut = new net.Socket();


clientIn.connect(configPort, configHost, function () {
  console.log('Conectado');
 
});


clientIn.on('data', function (data) {

  console.log(data);

}

clientOut.connect(configPort, configHost, function () {
  console.log("Conectado");

}

clientOut.on('data', function (data) {
 console.log(data);
}
   
   clientOut.disconnect();
```

Comment: `clientOut.destroy();` ou `clientOut.pause` poderia resolver. Um encerrar pra sempre e o outro pode ser ativado de voltar.

Comment: ``clientOut.destroy()`` e ``clientOut.pause()`` , todos dois funcionaram.Muito Obrigado pela ajuda @MauryDeveloper

Comment: sabe me informar como eu faria para restartar o ``clientIn`` @MauryDeveloper ?

Comment: O módulo net é muito limitado, eu uso frameworks pra ajudar, mas pra resetar eu usaria clientIn.destroy().

Comment: Ok @AnittaDeveloper vou estar verificando isso  muito obrigado pela ajuda :)....Poderia me informar algumas bibliotecas que eu poderia estar usando para melhorar o desempenho da minha aplicação ?

Comment: eu uso socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou usar a biblioteca do socket.io junto com o express ?
Fica bem fácil o processo para entender e utilizar.

[documentação do socket.io](https://socket.io/)

O servidor socket exemplo: socket.js, depois node socket.js está tá no ar.

```
const port =  process.env.PORT || 3001; //porta padrão
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io'); 
var io = socketio(http, {perMessageDeflate: false});
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.info(`Servidor socket inicializado usando express na porta ${port}`);
});

io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client entrou [id=${socket.id}]`);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.info(`Client saiu [id=${socket.id}]`);
    });
    socket.on("mensagem-enviada", dados => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('mensagem-repassada', dados);
        console.log(`mensagem recebida e repassada: ${JSON.stringify(dados)}`)
    });
});
```

Já no lado do cliente, pode-se usar assim:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3001', {transports: ['websocket']});
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("socket conseguiu conectar ao servidor");
    }); 
socket.on('mensagem-repassada', data => {
      console.log("mensagem recebida que foi repassada:");
      console.log(data);
    });
    // para enviar ao socket para basta chamar a funçao enviarMensagem passando os dados que vai enviar o servidor
    function enviarMensagem(dados){ 
        socket.emit("mensagem-enviada", dados);
    }
  </script>
```